# Duplicate records from element in a list using Python

Tags: python

I have been working on a functionality to get the synonyms from a data set or sample using the following snippet and want to print Concepts and related Synonyms but the actual output is printing it twice making it difficult to understand.

Code :

```
for rt in self.raw_tokens:
            concept = None
            if rt.startswith('<'):
                # if it's a concept (entity):
                if 'value' in ElementTree.fromstring(rt).attrib:
                    string_token = ElementTree.fromstring(rt).text
                    concept = ElementTree.fromstring(rt).tag
                # if it's a synonym, just use the text and strip the tag from the sample:
                else:
                    string_token = ElementTree.fromstring(rt).text
                    #print('Token: [' + rt + ']')
                    print("Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<%s> = %s" %(ElementTree.fromstring(rt).tag,string_token))
                    #print('CONCEPT: ' + concept)
            else:
                    string_token = rt
            toks.append((concept, string_token))
```

```
Expected output :
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_LOVE>I like</I_LOVE>> = I like
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_WANTS>NEED</I_WANTS>> = NEED
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<NEW_YORK>NEW YORK</NEW_YORK>> = NEW YORK
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_WANTS>wish</I_WANTS>> = wish
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<NEW_YORK>BIG APPLE</NEW_YORK>> = BIG APPLE
```

```
Current :

Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_LOVE>I like</I_LOVE>> = I like
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_WANTS>NEED</I_WANTS>> = NEED
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<NEW_YORK>NEW YORK</NEW_YORK>> = NEW YORK
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_WANTS>wish</I_WANTS>> = wish
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<NEW_YORK>BIG APPLE</NEW_YORK>> = BIG APPLE
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_LOVE>I like</I_LOVE>> = I like
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_WANTS>NEED</I_WANTS>> = NEED
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<NEW_YORK>NEW YORK</NEW_YORK>> = NEW YORK
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<I_WANTS>wish</I_WANTS>> = wish
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<<NEW_YORK>BIG APPLE</NEW_YORK>> = BIG APPLE
```

Any suggestions how to make it print unique sample ?

Comment: You actually save your list into a `Set()` while looping and after that printing it after the loop is done.

Comment: I tried using List(set(rt)) but the result was not the one mentioned under expected:Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'V', ' ', 'i', 'e', 'k', 'I', 'O', '>', 'l', '/', 'E', '_', '<', 'L'}> = I like
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'N', 'W', 'I', '>', 'T', '/', 'A', 'E', '_', '<', 'S', 'D'}> = NEED
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{' ', 'R', 'N', 'W', 'O', '>', 'Y', '/', 'E', '_', 'K', '<'}> = NEW YORK
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'i', 'h', 'N', 'w', 'W', 's', 'I', '>', 'T', '/', 'A', '_', '<', 'S'}> = wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant by using a `Set`:

```
toks = set()
for rt in self.raw_tokens:
            concept = None
            if rt.startswith('<'):
                # if it's a concept (entity):
                if 'value' in ElementTree.fromstring(rt).attrib:
                    string_token = ElementTree.fromstring(rt).text
                    concept = ElementTree.fromstring(rt).tag
                # if it's a synonym, just use the text and strip the tag from the sample:
                else:
                    string_token = ElementTree.fromstring(rt).text
            else:
                    string_token = rt
            if not (concept, string_token) in toks:
                print("Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<%s> = %s" %(concept,string_token))
                toks.add((concept, string_token))
```

Comment: Thanks but it still is printing the duplicates ,with the same output-                                         ```Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'I_LOVE'}> = I like
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'I_WANTS'}> = NEED
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'NEW_YORK', 'I_WANTS'}> = NEW YORK
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'I_WANTS'}> = wish
Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'NEW_YORK', 'I_WANTS'}> = BIG APPLE            Concepts & Synonyms are present in the sample :<{'I_LOVE'}> = I like```

Comment: @KomalAneja I changed the code according to what I understood. Unfortunataly I don't have enough information about your data to makes sure it's 100% what you need. But It's another try.